# get_terms() order not follow hierarchy

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is how I get all terms, including children, of a custom hierarchical taxonomy:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'obra_tema',
);

$themes = get_terms($args);
```

Very simple. But instead the list look like that:

1. Books
2. Cars
3. Others
4. DVD (child of Others)

The function return

1. Books
2. Cars
3. DVD (child of Others)
4. Others

How can I show terms in the same order of dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Have not tried this, but it should be something like this

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'obra_tema',
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

$themes = get_terms($args);
```

You might have to adjust the order field or the order by direction.

Comment: The problem is terms has not the expected ID order. What I can't understand is why `wp_list_categories()` return the correct order and `get_terms()` not.

Comment: In that case you might want to consider a plugin to order them manually in the admin panel.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I've used this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-post-order/. Pretty simple and easy to use drag and drop.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I found a solution here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/259175/how-to-display-child-term-of-current-terms-parent-taxonomy